# Override EqualityComparer for LINQ to SQL class

Tags: c#, .net, observablecollection

I want to override the EqualityComparer for one of my LINQ to SQL classes (autogenerated by visual studio) so that when I look for a match with IndexOf, it will use my comparison instead of whatever it would do for this class.  It does not seem to work, and my override does not get called.

Here is the logic for the comparison:

```
ClientFileList f = new ClientFileList();
f.ClientID = -1 * lines;
f.JobID = JobID;
f.DRSCode = aParts[0];
f.DocumentNumber = aParts[1];
f.Revision = aParts[2];
f.Title = aParts[3];
f.TitleLine2 = aParts[4];
f.TitleLine3 = aParts[5];
f.SheetNumber = aParts[6];
f.Status = aParts[7];
f.ColorCode = ColorCode;

if(oCFile.IndexOf(f)==-1)
{
    // this element is not a duplicate
    oCFile.Add(f);
}
```

and here is my extended class to override the EqualityComparer:

```
public partial class ClientFileList : EqualityComparer<ClientFileList>
{
    public override bool Equals(ClientFileList x, ClientFileList y)
    {
        //throw new NotImplementedException();
        return (x.DocumentNumber == y.DocumentNumber &&
                x.Revision == y.Revision);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode(ClientFileList obj)
    {
        String s = obj.DocumentNumber + obj.Revision;
        return s.GetHashCode();
        //throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

What I am hoping for is if a document with matching DocumentNumber and Revision is already in the database, I don't want to add it again (this is implemented while reading a delimited text file and inserting into the database).  MSDN documentation on IndexOf seemed to indicate that it would use the EqualityComparer . . . but I am not seeing that behavior.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You should not be editing the answer into the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to override the EqualityComparer for one of my LINQ to SQL classes

I really don't think you do. I think you want to override the `Equals` method, and probably implement `IEquatable<T>`. `EqualityComparer` is meant for an object which is able to compare objects of *other* types - for example an `AgeComparer` might derive from `EqualityComparer<Person>`.

If you override `Equals(object)` and `GetHashCode`, and also implement `IEquatable<T>`, then I'd expect `IndexOf` to work, assuming that `oCFile` is a `List<ClientFileList>` or something similar (you haven't told us). However, it won't affect how LINQ to SQL itself issues queries, of course.

Comment: Thanks . . . That worked well.  Except that with IEquitable the Equals and GetHashCode methods are not overrides, rather are simply implemented.  I put the working code in my question for reference.

Comment: @PaulGibson: No, you're still overriding `Equals(object)` and `GetHashCode` from `System.Object`. Or at least, you *should* override `Equals(object)` - but you're not doing so. You should be seeing a warning about `GetHashCode`...

Comment: Jon,  when I had `public override equals . . . ` I was getting an error that there was no suitable method found to override, similar with the GetHashCode . . . in the auto generated class definition the declaration is: `public partial class ClientFileList : INotifyPropertyChanging, INotifyPropertyChanged { . . . }`

Comment: It compiles as posted above with no warnings by the way . . . I am not sure why, but am glad it works.

Comment: Ok, I think it's because above my Equals function is for my class.  If I override with `public override bool Equals(object obj) { .... }` then I don't get the error (and doing the same with GetHashCode).  So it looks like implementing a type specific method for Equals and GetHashCode will not need the override.

Comment: @PaulGibson: But you *should* still override `Object.GetHashCode` and `Object.Equals` - that's what I'm saying. It's very weird if you get different results based on *exactly* how you call the method.

Comment: @PaulGibson: Furthermore, I note that you're not *really* fully implementing the `GetHashCode` part - you shouldn't have a parameter (it's meant to get the hash code of `this`). So it's only working because `List<T>.IndexOf` doesn't use the hash code - if you started to use it as a dictionary key for example, you'd have problems.

Comment: Jon,  thanks for your time!  I am wondering if this may be a case of me wanting to constrain the Equals for my particular case, but allow the base implementation to remain for some reason.  That is, perhaps under the hood the base implementation is used and my more constrained version would cause unanticipated side effects.  Whereas I know that my specific Equals method is only called by the method that reads in a text file.  I will set up some experiments and play around with this.  Thanks again for your help.

Comment: @PaulGibson: If you *really* want that, I would recommend implementing `IEqualityComparer<T>` in a separate class, and then calling `list.Contains(item, comparer)` to check whether the list contains the item in a particular way. Or just use `list.Any(x => x.RevisionNumber == y.RevisionNumber && x.DocumentNumber == y.DocumentNumber)`. I would *strongly* advise against having one object expose different notions of equality in a non-obvious manner.